# unable to loop the last url with paging limits

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, skip

I'm a newbie to web-scraping - I set up a loop to scrape with 37900 records. Due to the way the url/ server is being set up, there's a limit of 200 records displayed in each url. Each url ends with 'skip=200', or mulitiple of 200 to loop to the next url page where the next 200 records are displayed. Eventually I want to loop through all urls and append them as a table.

I created two loops shown as below - one for creating urls with skip= every 200 records, and another one to get response of each of these urls, then append them to a single dataframe.

However I run into an error on my last url and unable to append these jsons into a single dataframe.

```
"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Invalid value 'i37800' for $skip query option found. The $skip query option requires a non-negative integer value."
```

Edited: after removing the i after 'skip=' on my url, the second loop threw me this error

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

When I pop this url
https://~/Projects?&$skip=37800 the records are properly displayed, so I'm not sure why python threw me this error.
Please see below my codes - Would appreciate any suggestions to fix this error and loops!

Thanks!

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

records = range(37900)
skip = records[0::200]

Page = []
for i in skip:
    endpoint = "https://~/Projects?&$skip=i{}".format(i)
    Page.append(endpoint)

tbls = []
for j in Page():
    response = session.get(j) #session here refers to requests.Session() I had to set up to authenticate my access to these urls
    responsejs = response.json()
    responsepd = pd.DataFrame(responsejs['value']) #I only want to extract header called 'value' in each json
    tbls.append(responsepd)
```

Comment: `skip=37800` != `skip=i37800`, note the extra `i` in your format string. Double check how the URLs should be entered

Comment: thanks @G.Anderson! I removed the 'i' after skip= so it stops throwing me the error.  ```for i in skip:
    endpoint = "https://~/Projects?&$skip={}".format(i)
    Page.append(endpoint)``` .  but how come i'm unable to call the urls in my list in my second loop (error: ```'list' object is not callable```)?

Comment: You should be getting a totally different error, from what I can tell; `Page` is a list, so `Page.values()` should throw `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'`. For more specifics, you need to [edit] your question with the full error traceback

Comment: yep you're right. I was trying ```Page()``` instead of ```Page.values()```, I edited the code to display error messages accordingly

Comment: You still can't _call_ `Page` with parentheses, because `Page` is still a list. `Page():`->`Page:`

Comment: it is still throwing me error ```AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append''``` after changing it to ```Page:``` sorry i'm too new to this, does it mean i can't append my jsons to a single list?

Comment: There's no reason you shouldn't be able to append json to a list; I would check the `type()` of each of your objects. That error is about what you're appending _to_, not what is _being_ appended. At this point the code has changed enough, it might warrant a new question. Consider posting the updated code and full error traceback into a new question if you can't figure it out.

Comment: thanks @G.Anderson, I've put it up as a separate question here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58599431/create-loop-to-extract-urls-to-json-and-csv>