# create loop to extract urls to json and csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, loops, url

I set up a loop to **scrape** with 37900 records. Due to the way the url/ server is being set up, there's a limit of 200 records displayed in each url. Each url ends with 'skip=200', or mulitiple of 200 to loop to the next url page where the next 200 records are displayed. Eventually I want to loop through all urls and append them as a table. The related posted [unable to loop the last url with paging limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494208/unable-to-loop-the-last-url-with-paging-limits)

I created two loops shown as below - one for creating urls with skip= every 200 records, and another one to get response of each of these urls, then another loop to read json and append them to a single dataframe.

I'm not sure what's missing in my second loop - so far it only produces json for the first URL page but not the subsequent pages. I have the feeling that the usl jsons are not appended to the list json = [] and so it prevents looping and append the jsons in csv. Any suggestions on modifying the loops and improving these codes are appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

records = range(37900)
skip = records[0::200]

Page = []
for i in skip:
    endpoint = "https://~/Projects?&$skip={}".format(i)
    Page.append(endpoint)

jsnlist = []
for j in Page:
    response = session.get(j) #session here refers to requests.Session() I had to set up to authenticate my access to these urls
    responsejs = response.json()
    responsejsval = responsejs['value'] #I only want to extract header called 'value' in each json
    with open('response2jsval.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(jsnlist, outfile)

concat = pd.DataFrame()
for k in jsnlist:
        df = pd.DataFrame(k) #list to df
        concat = concat.append(df, ignore_index = True)
        print(concat)
```

Comment: `json` is name of module - so don't use this name as variable `json = []`

Comment: a) don't call your own objects `json` because that just masks the actual `json` module and b) `with open('response2jsval.json', 'w') as outfile:` just keeps obliterating any data you have saved because you open in `w` mode. Very quickly, point (a) makes this code untenable.

Comment: first get all data from pages and create one dictionary or list  with all data and later save it. Writing with `w` you remove previous content. But if you even will write in append mode `a` then you may create incorrect JSON file.

Comment: It could, in theory, create JSON-Lines, but I'm pretty sure that isn't what you want. Go with the suggestion by @furas and take it in two stages; first aggregate the responses into a single object (why write to disk here?) and then transfer the whole lot to a df

Comment: thanks both! will give it a go on creating a dictionary! I've also updated the object name in the example code above. no I was thinking to create JSON-lines since my data isn't nested. in that case which writing mode should I use to write the json file?

Comment: if you want to open many times and add new line then you should use `a` (append). Using `w` (write) it removes previous content when you open.

Answer (score 0):

*I have nothing to test against*

I think you massively over-complicated this. You've since edited the question but there's a couple of points to make:

1. You define `jsnlist = []` but never use it. Why?
2. You called your own object `json` (now gone but I'm not sure whether you understand why). Calling your own object `json` will just supersede the actual module, and the whole code will grind to a halt before you even got into a loop
3. There is no reason at all to save this data to disk before trying to create a dataframe
4. Opening the `.json` file in write mode (`'w'`) will wipe all existing data on each iteration of your loop
5. Appending JSON to a file will not give a valid format to be parsed when read back in. At best, it might be JSONLines
6. Appending DataFrames in a loop has terrible complexity because it requires copying of the original data each time.

Your approach will be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

records = range(37900)
skip = records[0::200]

Page = []
for i in skip:
    endpoint = "https://~/Projects?&$skip={}".format(i)
    Page.append(endpoint)

jsnlist = []
for j in Page:
    response = session.get(j) #session here refers to requests.Session() I had to set up to authenticate my access to these urls
    responsejs = response.json()
    responsejsval = responsejs['value'] #I only want to extract header called 'value' in each json
    jsnlist.append(responsejsval)

df = pd.DataFrame(jsnlist)
```

`df = pd.DataFrame(jsnlist)` might take some work, but you'll need to show what we're up against. I'd need to see `responsejs['value']` to answer fully.

Comment: To your questions @roganjosh Q1: I was hoping to create a list that will allow me to access to individual json object later on e.g. to create a dataframe;  Q2 yep i modified my original object name in this example but definitely made a mistake of naming it to json the actual module! Q5 & Q6: would creating a dictionary solve the issues? indeed i do have problem reading the json back using this approach. `responsejs['value']` is a collection of 30+ parameters and data respectively, e.g. `responsejs['value'] = {'Name': 'Jane'; 'DateofBirth': '28-10-2019'; 'Country': 'United Kingdom'}`. thanks.

Comment: @byc to the latter point, I suspect my code would give you the df you wanted? It's already parsed into a dict and pandas will take a list of dicts quite happily

Comment: @byc I have to go to bed sorry, getting late. I'll pick it up again tomorrow if there are issues :)

Comment: sure thanks for helping out. your answer is very similar to my original example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494208/unable-to-loop-the-last-url-with-paging-limits). but like you and @fura said appending json to a file creates issues when reading back, so i wonder if creating dictionary can solve this issue. what are the plausible file format in this case?